# Loading Multiple services format in Dependency Injection folder

Tags: xml, symfony, yaml

In my Dependency Injection folder inside my bundle

```
class AcmeDemoExtension extends Extension
{
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.xml');
}

public function getAlias()
 {
    return 'acme_demo';
 }
}
```

I created another services in Yaml format

Is it possible to load multiple services in DependencyInjection Folder?

something like

```
   $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.xml');
   $loader = new YmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('anotherservices.yml');
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible! Just try it.

Use the `php app/console debug:container` [command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#debugging-services) to see your changes.